# Check/uncheck CheckBox (GridViewCheckBoxColumn)

Tags: wpf, gridview, checkbox, telerik

I can't check/uncheck the `CheckBox` in the `gridview` cell. I think it is disabled. How am I going to do this? Looking for your responce..

[image: Checkbox]

Xaml Code:

```
<telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Customer"/>
                    <telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn Header="Assigned" AutoSelectOnEdit="True"/>
                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            </telerik:RadGridView>
</telerik:RadGridview.Columns>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add one of the following commands:

```
 EditTriggers="Default"
```

- two clicks are needed to change the value of the checkbox.

```
EditTriggers="CellClick"
```

- only one click is needed to change the value of the checkbox.

Comment: satisfied now? sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

If your RadGridView is ReadOnly then you can't edit any cell.

```
<telerik:RadGridView Name="MyGridView" IsReadOnly="True">
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Customer" DataMemberBinding="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
        <telerik:GridViewCheckBoxColumn Header="Assigned" AutoSelectOnEdit="True"/>
    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

If you add more details then it will be easy for others to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to clarify zaman's answer, because you can have editable cells in a readonly grid.

```
<telerik:RadGridView ShowGroupPanel="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
...
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Amount" IsReadOnly="False">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding AmountText, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
...
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that following XAML is the best solution to this problem. It works even when your grid/column is in ReadOnly mode. Also, you don't have to do 2 or 3 clicks to change value of checkbox.

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding IsActive}" IsReadOnly="True">
   <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Office_Black"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
```